# java 32-bits windows : determine maximum heap available when launching JRE

Tags: java, memory, launch4j

Our Java application (that we want to keep compatible with 32-bit windows computers, hence using 32-bit JRE) is memory intensive and we would like to give it the maximum available memory when launching JRE (using Xmx parameter).

While theoretically 32-bits gives 4Gb of allocable memory, we understood that given Windows' memory management, it is more constrainted by the largest continuous block of memory available. A bit of testing has shown us that a value of 1024mb is most likely to work on most computers.

We're now looking into the **best approach to allocate the largest heap memory available when starting the application**: is there any approach other than trial-error (i.e. launch JRE with 4GB, and then decrease until it works)?

Also, we're launching our application using Launch4J: would this provide additional options to define the largest heap memory possible?

Comment: 32bits give you 2GiB. Th only way to allocate is writing a script that tries to allocate different amounts via `-Xmx` and continue if the process exits with an error code. Keep in mind that if you allocate the max memory, the OS will run out of virtual memory which you might not want. Please note: the largest memory available to allocate depends on the max continuous block of virtual memory.

Comment: One more note: you dont want java to ever use swap, full garbage collection hitting the swap can literally take minutes.

Comment: Thanks. And is there a way to use Launch4J to either script the trials or, at least detect if there was a memory issue and display an elegant error message?

Comment: I have zero knowledge on Launch4j, we did wrote our own launcher in C++ (loads jvm.dll and so on). You simply cant start java with large heap, so you can detect that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the win32 code I use to do this in our JNI based launchers - the original inspiration for this approach was a website that I'm no longer able to find - hopefully it will be of use (I have no idea if Launch4J has something like this - if they don't, you should ask them to add it ;-)  ).  I use 62 for permGenMB.  maxHeapMB is the maximum size you are going to ask for (768, 1024) - the getMaxHeapAvailable() function will return the size below that limit that machine can actually allocate for you.

Note that win32 has ~3GB of addressable memory, but you won't be able to get a chunk that big - the JVM requires that the memory be in a single allocatable block - your machine may have 5GB of RAM available, but if the biggest open block only has 1GB in it, then that's the max the JVM can get.

```
static const DWORD NUM_BYTES_PER_MB = 1024 * 1024;

bool canAllocate(DWORD bytes)
{
    LPVOID lpvBase;

    lpvBase = VirtualAlloc(NULL, bytes, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (lpvBase == NULL) return false;

    VirtualFree(lpvBase, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return true;
}

int getMaxHeapAvailable(int permGenMB, int maxHeapMB)
{
    DWORD       originalMaxHeapBytes = 0;
    DWORD       maxHeapBytes = 0;
    int         numMemChunks = 0;
    SYSTEM_INFO     sSysInfo;
    DWORD       maxPermBytes = permGenMB * NUM_BYTES_PER_MB;     // Perm space is in addition to the heap size
    DWORD       numBytesNeeded = 0;

    GetSystemInfo(&sSysInfo);

    // jvm aligns as follows: 
    // quoted from size_t GenCollectorPolicy::compute_max_alignment() of jdk 7 hotspot code:
    //      The card marking array and the offset arrays for old generations are
    //      committed in os pages as well. Make sure they are entirely full (to
    //      avoid partial page problems), e.g. if 512 bytes heap corresponds to 1
    //      byte entry and the os page size is 4096, the maximum heap size should
    //      be 512*4096 = 2MB aligned.

    // card_size computation from CardTableModRefBS::SomePublicConstants of jdk 7 hotspot code
    int card_shift  = 9;
    int card_size   = 1 << card_shift;

    DWORD alignmentBytes = sSysInfo.dwPageSize * card_size;

    maxHeapBytes = maxHeapMB * NUM_BYTES_PER_MB + 50*NUM_BYTES_PER_MB; // 50 is an overhead fudge factory per https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6463655 (they had 28, I'm bumping it 'just in case')

    // make it fit in the alignment structure
    maxHeapBytes = maxHeapBytes + (maxHeapBytes % alignmentBytes);
    numMemChunks = maxHeapBytes / alignmentBytes;
    originalMaxHeapBytes = maxHeapBytes;

    // loop and decrement requested amount by one chunk
    // until the available amount is found
    numBytesNeeded = maxHeapBytes + maxPermBytes; 
    while (!canAllocate(numBytesNeeded) && numMemChunks > 0) 
    {
        numMemChunks --;
        maxHeapBytes = numMemChunks * alignmentBytes;
        numBytesNeeded = maxHeapBytes + maxPermBytes;
    }

    if (numMemChunks == 0) return 0;

    // we can allocate the requested size, return it now
    if (maxHeapBytes == originalMaxHeapBytes) return maxHeapMB;

    // calculate the new MaxHeapSize in megabytes
    return maxHeapBytes / NUM_BYTES_PER_MB;
}
```